# in WSUS is there a way to set the DOWNLOAD AUTOMATICALLY at night but APPROVED MANUALLY in the morning what update to use/deploy to the clients?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, wsus, windows-update

right now when i approved updates in the morning the WSUS eats up the bandwidth of the internet which is affecting our business operations.

is there a way to set the DOWNLOAD AUTOMATICALLY at night but APPROVED MANUALLY in the morning what update to use/deploy to the clients?

my setup is Win2008 R2-server / Win7-clients

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/73759/126632

Answer (score 0):

For controlling the the exact time when updates are downloaded and installed, you can use Wuinstall (http://www.wuinstall.com) 
It is a commmand line tool for windows updates that can be scripted.
For exampe at night, you call wuinstall /download on the machines to be updated (e.g remote via psexec), and whenever you like to install usw wuinstall /install. There is also a /download_cache option that can downlad updates to a central location to save even more bandwidth (=updates are downloaded just once to a shared drive and then distributed to the target machines via local netwok)

Answer (score 0):

If WAN bandwidth is your concern, why are you not hosting the update files on your WSUS server?  Then only one machine is responsible for downloading everything over the WAN connection and all of the clients download from it over the LAN.